# Forward linked list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++17

I wrote a linked list implementation in C++ to learn the concepts about linked lists as well as C++(17). I decided to use `std::unique_ptr` to help me avoid leaks and also took a lot of inspiration from `std::forward_list`.

I am not so worried about bugs, because I wrote some tests and they seem to pass. I am interested in knowing more about what is missing from my implementation compared to a gcc implementation and what the weaknesses are of my implementation. Also, interested in suggestions for making some parts of the implementation simpler (especially thinking about the complexity of `merge` and `sort` functions).

```cpp
#ifndef CUSTOM_LINKED_LIST_HPP
#define CUSTOM_LINKED_LIST_HPP

#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace custom {

struct node_base {
    node_base(): next(nullptr) {}
    node_base(std::unique_ptr<node_base>&& n): next(std::move(n)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<node_base> next;
};

template<typename T>
struct node : node_base {
    node(std::unique_ptr<node_base>&& n, T d): node_base(std::move(n)), data(std::move(d)) {}
    T data;
};

template<typename T, typename node_ptr = node_base*>
class linked_list_forward_iterator {
public:
    // https://www.internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using pointer = T*;

    linked_list_forward_iterator(node_ptr ptr): m_ptr(ptr) {};
    // copy constructor, copy assignment operator, destructor= default

    reference operator*() const {
        return data_node()->data;
    }

    pointer operator->() {
        return &data_node()->data;
    }

    bool operator==(linked_list_forward_iterator<T, node_ptr> const& other) const {
        return this->m_ptr == other.m_ptr;
    }

    bool operator!=(linked_list_forward_iterator<T, node_ptr> const& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    // prefix increment
    node_ptr operator++() {
        assert(m_ptr);
        m_ptr = m_ptr->next.get();
        return m_ptr;
    }

    // postfix increment
    node_ptr operator++(int) {
        linked_list_forward_iterator<T, node_ptr> tmp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return tmp.m_ptr;
    }

    node<T>* data_node() const {
        return static_cast<node<T>*>(m_ptr);
    }

    node_ptr m_ptr;
};

template<typename T>
class linked_list {

static_assert(std::is_object_v<T>, "T must be object");

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointner = T const*;
    using iterator = linked_list_forward_iterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = linked_list_forward_iterator<const T>;

    // constructors && assignments
    linked_list(): m_head(std::make_unique<node_base>(nullptr)) {}

    explicit linked_list(size_type count): linked_list(count, T{}) {}

    explicit linked_list(size_type count, const_reference value)
    : linked_list()
    {
        node_base* last_node = m_head.get();
        for (size_type i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            last_node->next = std::make_unique<node<T>>(nullptr, value);
            last_node = last_node->next.get();
        }
    }

    explicit linked_list(std::initializer_list<T> init): linked_list(init.begin(), init.end()) {}

    template<class InputIt>
    linked_list(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    : linked_list()
    {
        node_base* last_node = m_head.get();
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            last_node->next = std::make_unique<node<T>>(nullptr, *it);
            last_node = last_node->next.get();
        }
    }

    linked_list(const linked_list& other): linked_list(other.cbegin(), other.cend()) {}
    linked_list(linked_list&& other) = default;
    ~linked_list() = default;

    linked_list& operator=(linked_list&& other) = default;
    linked_list& operator=(const linked_list& other) {
        linked_list<T> copy {other};
        swap(copy);
        return *this;
    }

    linked_list& operator=(std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
        *this = linked_list<T>(ilist);
        return *this;
    }

    void assign(size_type count, const T& value) {
        *this = linked_list<T>(count, value);
    }

    template<class InputIt>
    void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
        *this = linked_list<T>(first, last);
    }

    void assign(std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
        *this = linked_list<T>(ilist);
    }

    //  Element access

    T& front() {
        assert(m_head);
        return *begin();
    }

    T const& front() const {
        assert(m_head);
        return *cbegin();
    }

    // capacity

    size_type size() const {
        size_type size = 0;
        for (auto it = cbegin(); it != cend(); it++) {
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return !m_head->next;
    }

    // iterators

    iterator before_begin() {
        return iterator(m_head.get());
    }

    const_iterator before_begin() const {
        return cbefore_begin();
    }

    const_iterator cbefore_begin() const {
        return const_iterator(m_head.get());
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(m_head->next.get());
    }

    const_iterator begin() const {
        return cbegin();
    }

    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return const_iterator(m_head->next.get());
    }

    iterator end() {
        return nullptr;
    }

    const_iterator end() const {
        return cend();
    }

    const_iterator cend() const {
        return nullptr;
    }

    // modifiers

    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, T value) {
        assert(pos.m_ptr);
        node_base* my_node = pos.m_ptr;
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next = std::move(my_node->next);
        std::unique_ptr<node<T>> new_node = std::make_unique<node<T>>(std::move(old_next), std::move(value));
        my_node->next = std::move(new_node);
        return my_node->next.get();
    }

    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value) {
        assert(pos.m_ptr);
        iterator insert_pos = pos.m_ptr;
        for (size_type i=0; i<count; i++) {
            insert_pos = insert_after(insert_pos.m_ptr, value);
        }
        return insert_pos;
    }

    template<class InputIt>
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last) {
        assert(pos.m_ptr);
        iterator insert_pos = pos.m_ptr;
        for (auto it = first; it != last; it++) {
            insert_pos = insert_after(insert_pos.m_ptr, *it);
        }
        return insert_pos;
    }

    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
        return insert_after(pos, ilist.begin(), ilist.end());
    }

    template<class... Args>
    iterator emplace_after(const_iterator pos, Args&&... args) {
        assert(pos.m_ptr);
        node_base* my_node = pos.m_ptr;
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next = std::move(my_node->next);
        std::unique_ptr<node<T>> new_node = std::make_unique<node<T>>(std::move(old_next), T(std::forward<Args...>(args...)));
        my_node->next = std::move(new_node);
        return my_node->next.get();
    }

    void push_front(const T& value) {
        insert_after(cbefore_begin(), value);
    }

    void push_front(T&& value) {
        insert_after(cbefore_begin(), std::move(value));
    }

    template<class... Args>
    reference emplace_front(Args&&... args) {
        return *emplace_after(cbefore_begin(), std::forward<Args...>(args...));
    }

    void pop_front() {
        erase_after(cbefore_begin());
    }

    iterator erase_after(const_iterator pos) {
        assert(pos.m_ptr);
        node_base* my_node = pos.m_ptr;
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next = std::move(my_node->next);
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> new_next = std::move(old_next->next);        
        my_node->next = std::move(new_next);
        return my_node->next.get();
    }

    iterator erase_after(const_iterator first, const_iterator last) {
        // get prev to last node
        assert(first.m_ptr);
        if (first == last) {
            return last.m_ptr;
        }
        node_base* first_node = first.m_ptr;
        node_base* prev_to_last_node = get_prev_to_last_node(first, last).m_ptr;
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> new_next = std::move(prev_to_last_node->next);        
        first_node->next = std::move(new_next);
        return first_node->next.get();
    }

    void clear() {
        erase_after(cbefore_begin(), cend());
    }

    void swap(linked_list& other) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(m_head, other.m_head);
    }

    // operations

    void merge(linked_list& other) {
        // assumes sorted list
        if (this == &other) {
            return;
        }
        auto it_1 = this->before_begin();
        auto it_2 = other.before_begin();
        while (!other.empty()) {
            if (end() == it_1.m_ptr->next.get()) {
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> node_to_move = std::move(it_2.m_ptr->next);
                it_1.m_ptr->next = std::move(node_to_move);
                continue;
            }
            T const& val1 = static_cast<node<T>*>(it_1.m_ptr->next.get())->data;
            T const& val2 = static_cast<node<T>*>(it_2.m_ptr->next.get())->data;
            if (val1 > val2) {
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> node_to_move = std::move(it_2.m_ptr->next);
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next_of_node_to_move = std::move(node_to_move->next);
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> new_next_of_node_to_move = std::move(it_1.m_ptr->next);
                it_2.m_ptr->next = std::move(old_next_of_node_to_move);
                node_to_move->next = std::move(new_next_of_node_to_move);
                it_1.m_ptr->next = std::move(node_to_move);
            }
            it_1 ++;
        }
    }

    void splice_after(const_iterator pos, linked_list& other) {
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next = std::move(pos.m_ptr->next);
        auto before_end_it = get_prev_to_last_node(other.cbegin(), other.cend());
        before_end_it.m_ptr->next = std::move(old_next);
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> node_to_move = std::move(other.m_head->next);
        pos.m_ptr->next = std::move(node_to_move);
    }

    void splice_after(const_iterator pos, linked_list& other, const_iterator it) {
        (void) other;
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next = std::move(pos.m_ptr->next);
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> node_to_move = std::move(it.m_ptr->next);
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> others_remaining_next = std::move(node_to_move->next);
        it.m_ptr->next = std::move(others_remaining_next);
        node_to_move->next = std::move(old_next);
        pos.m_ptr->next = std::move(node_to_move);
    }

    void remove(const T& value) {
        return remove_if([&value](const T& val){ return val == value; });
    }

    template<class UnaryPredicate>
    void remove_if(UnaryPredicate p) {
        auto it = before_begin();
        while (it.m_ptr->next.get() != nullptr) {
            T const& val = static_cast<node<T>*>(it.m_ptr->next.get())->data;
            if (!p(val)) {
                it++;
                continue;
            }
            std::unique_ptr<node_base> remaining = std::move(it.m_ptr->next->next);
            it.m_ptr->next = std::move(remaining);
        }
    }

    void reverse() {
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> following = nullptr;
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> current = std::move(m_head->next);
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> previous = nullptr;
        while (current) {
            following = std::move(current->next);

            current->next = std::move(previous);
            previous = std::move(current);
            current = std::move(following);
        }
        m_head->next = std::move(previous);
    }

    void unique() {
        auto it = begin();
        while (it.m_ptr->next.get() != nullptr) {
            T const& previous_val = static_cast<node<T>*>(it.m_ptr)->data;
            T const& val = static_cast<node<T>*>(it.m_ptr->next.get())->data;
            if (previous_val == val) {
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> node_to_remove = std::move(it.m_ptr->next);
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> new_next = std::move(node_to_remove->next);
                it.m_ptr->next = std::move(new_next);
            } else {
                it ++;
            }
        }
    }

    void sort() { 
        return sort([](const T& a, const T& b){ return a < b; });
    }

    template<class Compare>
    void sort(Compare comp) {
        merge_sort(m_head->next, comp);
    }

private:
    const_iterator get_prev_to_last_node(const_iterator first, const_iterator last) {
        assert(first.m_ptr);
        assert(first != last);
        auto it = first;
        auto prev_to_last_it = first;
        while (it != last) {
            prev_to_last_it = it++;
        }
        assert(prev_to_last_it.m_ptr);
        assert(prev_to_last_it.m_ptr->next.get() == last.m_ptr);
        return prev_to_last_it;
    }

    template<class Compare>
    void merge_sort(std::unique_ptr<node_base>& node_to_sort, Compare const& comp) {
        if (!node_to_sort || !node_to_sort->next) {
            return;
        }
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> other {nullptr};
        split_list(node_to_sort, other);
        assert(node_to_sort);
        assert(other);
        assert(debug_size(node_to_sort)-debug_size(other) <= 1);
        merge_sort(node_to_sort, comp);
        merge_sort(other, comp);
        assert(node_to_sort);
        assert(other);
        merge_sorted_nodes(node_to_sort, other, comp);
        assert(node_to_sort);
        assert(!other);
    }

    void split_list(
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>& begin_a,
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>& begin_b
    ) {
        assert(begin_a);
        assert(!begin_b);
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>* ptr_1 {&begin_a->next};
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>* ptr_2 {&begin_a};

        while (*ptr_1) {
            ptr_1 = &(*ptr_1)->next;
            if (*ptr_1) {
                ptr_1 = &(*ptr_1)->next;
                ptr_2 = &(*ptr_2)->next;
            }
        }

        begin_b = std::move((*ptr_2)->next);
        (*ptr_2)->next = nullptr;
        assert(begin_b);
    }

    template<class Compare>
    void merge_sorted_nodes(
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>& a,
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>& b,
        Compare const& comp
    ) {
        // assumes sorted list
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> tmp_base = std::make_unique<node_base>(std::move(a));
        std::unique_ptr<node_base>* current_node = &tmp_base;
        while (b) {
            if (!(*current_node)->next) {
                (*current_node)->next = std::move(b);
                b = nullptr;
                continue;
            }
            T const& val1 = static_cast<node<T>*>((*current_node)->next.get())->data;
            T const& val2 = static_cast<node<T>*>(b.get())->data;
            if (comp(val2, val1)) { // val2 < val1
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> node_to_move = std::move(b);
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> old_next_of_node_to_move = std::move(node_to_move->next);
                std::unique_ptr<node_base> new_next_of_node_to_move = std::move((*current_node)->next);
                b = std::move(old_next_of_node_to_move);
                node_to_move->next = std::move(new_next_of_node_to_move);
                (*current_node)->next = std::move(node_to_move);
            }
            current_node = &(*current_node)->next;
        }
        a = std::move(tmp_base->next);
    }

    std::size_t debug_size(std::unique_ptr<node_base> const& n) {
        std::unique_ptr<node_base> const * ptr = &n;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        while(*ptr) {
            ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    std::string debug_string(node_base const* n) {
        std::stringstream ss {};
        while (n) {
            ss << n << ", ";
            n = n->next.get();
        }
        return ss.str();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node_base> m_head;
};

template<class T>
bool operator==(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    auto it_1 = lhs.begin();
    auto it_2 = rhs.begin();
    while(it_1 != lhs.end() && it_2 != rhs.end()) {
        T const& val1 = it_1.data_node()->data;
        T const& val2 = it_2.data_node()->data;;
        if (!(val1 == val2)) {
            return false;
        }
        it_1 ++;
        it_2 ++;
    }
    return it_1 == lhs.end() && it_2 == rhs.end();
}

template<class T>
bool operator!=(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

template<class T>
bool operator<(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    auto it_1 = lhs.begin();
    auto it_2 = rhs.begin();
    while(it_1 != lhs.end() && it_2 != rhs.end()) {
        T const& val1 = it_1.data_node()->data;
        T const& val2 = it_2.data_node()->data;;
        if (!(val1 < val2)) {
            return false;
        }
        it_1 ++;
        it_2 ++;
    }
    return true;
}

template<class T>
bool operator<=(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    return (lhs == rhs) || (lhs < rhs);
}

template<class T>
bool operator>(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    return !(lhs <= rhs);
}

template<class T>
bool operator>=(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    return (lhs == rhs) || (lhs > rhs);
}

}

namespace std {

template<class T>
void swap(custom::linked_list<T>& lhs, custom::linked_list<T>& rhs) {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}

}

#endif
```

Edit:

And here are the tests I wrote:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "linked_list.hpp"

class LinkedListTestFixture : public testing::Test {
protected:
    LinkedListTestFixture() {
    }

    ~LinkedListTestFixture() = default;
};


TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_constructors_assignments_and_iterator) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_1 {2, 4, 9};
    EXPECT_EQ(3, my_list_1.size());
    std::vector<int> tmp_vector {1, 5, 6};
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_2 (tmp_vector.begin(), tmp_vector.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(3, my_list_2.size());
    my_list_2 = custom::linked_list<int>(std::size_t(5), 9);
    EXPECT_EQ(5, my_list_2.size());
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_3 = my_list_2;
    my_list_3 = my_list_1;
    my_list_3 = my_list_2;
    EXPECT_EQ(5, my_list_3.size());

    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_4 = std::move(my_list_3);
    EXPECT_EQ(5, my_list_4.size());

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector expected_values = {2, 4, 9};
    for (int const& x : my_list_1) {
        int const& y = expected_values.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_modifier_funcs) {
    custom::linked_list<double> my_list {1, 2, 3};
    my_list.insert_after(my_list.cbefore_begin(), -2);
    my_list.insert_after(my_list.cbefore_begin(), std::size_t(2), -3);
    custom::linked_list<double> tmp_list {10, 20};
    my_list.insert_after(my_list.cbegin(), tmp_list.cbegin(), tmp_list.cend());
    my_list.insert_after(my_list.cbegin(), {309, 319});
    my_list.emplace_after(my_list.cbefore_begin(), 45);
    my_list.push_front(44);
    my_list.emplace_front(42);
    my_list.emplace_front(42);
    my_list.pop_front();

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<double> expectation = {
        42, 44, 45, -3, 309, 319, 10, 20, -3, -2, 1, 2, 3
    };
    for (double const& x : my_list) {
        double const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    EXPECT_EQ(false, my_list.empty());
    my_list.clear();
    EXPECT_EQ(true, my_list.empty());
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_erase_after) {
    custom::linked_list<double> my_list {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    auto start_it = my_list.cbegin();
    auto stop_it = start_it;
    ++stop_it;
    ++stop_it;
    ++stop_it;
    my_list.erase_after(start_it, stop_it);

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<double> expectation = {1, 4, 5, 6};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (double const& x : my_list) {
        double const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_merge) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list {2, 4, 6, 7};
    my_list.merge(my_list);
    EXPECT_EQ(4, my_list.size());
    custom::linked_list<int> tmp_list {1, 5, 6};
    my_list.merge(tmp_list);
    custom::linked_list<int> tmp_list_2 {9, 9};
    my_list.merge(tmp_list_2);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, tmp_list.size());

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<int> expectation = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9, 9};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_splice) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list {1, 2, 3};
    custom::linked_list<int> tmp_list {10, 12};

    my_list.splice_after(my_list.cbegin(), tmp_list);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, tmp_list.size());

    tmp_list = {21, 22, 23};
    my_list.splice_after(my_list.cbegin(), tmp_list, tmp_list.cbegin());
    EXPECT_EQ(2, tmp_list.size());

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<int> expectation = {1, 22, 10, 12, 2, 3};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_remove) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1};
    my_list.remove(2);
    my_list.remove_if([](auto const& val) { return (val == 5) || (val == 7); });

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<int> expectation = {1, 3, 3, 1};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_reverse) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list {1, 2, 3};
    my_list.reverse();

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<int> expectation = {3, 2, 1};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_unique) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3,  2};
    my_list.unique();

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<int> expectation = {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_sort) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list {1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1};
    my_list.sort();

    auto i = 0;
    std::vector<int> expectation = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }

    my_list = {1, 3, 2};
    my_list.sort();

    i = 0;
    expectation = {1, 2, 3};
    EXPECT_EQ(expectation.size(), my_list.size());
    for (auto const& x : my_list) {
        auto const& y = expectation.at(i);
        EXPECT_EQ(y, x);
        i++;
    }
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_comparison_operators) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_1 {1, 2};
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_2 {7, 8, 9};
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_3 {7, 8, 9};

    EXPECT_FALSE(my_list_1 == my_list_2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_1 != my_list_2);
    EXPECT_FALSE(my_list_1 >= my_list_2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_1 <= my_list_2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_1 < my_list_2);
    EXPECT_FALSE(my_list_1 > my_list_2);

    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_2 == my_list_3);
    EXPECT_FALSE(my_list_2 != my_list_3);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_2 >= my_list_3);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_2 <= my_list_3);
    EXPECT_FALSE(my_list_2 < my_list_3);
    EXPECT_FALSE(my_list_2 > my_list_3);
}

TEST_F(LinkedListTestFixture, test_swap) {
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_1 {1, 2};
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_2 {7, 8, 9};
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_3 {7, 8, 9};
    custom::linked_list<int> my_list_4 {1, 2};

    std::swap(my_list_1, my_list_2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_1 == my_list_3);
    EXPECT_TRUE(my_list_2 == my_list_4);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that memory is well handled, and the API is tidy and tested. Nice code!

##### Performance

A number of operations do a lot more work than necessary. They're within expected algorithmic complexity (that's good), but constant multipliers do matter too.

For example, the `erase_after` call iterates over each erased element *twice* instead of *once*:

- Once during the call to `get_prev_to_last_node`.
- Once during the assignment to `next`, which leads to a chain of destructors being called.

Instead, it could simply pop the elements one at a time until the next element is the `end`.

##### Stack Overflow

Pertaining to the above "chain of destructors", a number of operations -- including the destructor -- are susceptible to stack overflows.

If you have a list `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4` then:

- Calling the destructor of 1,
- Will call the destructor of 2,
- Will call the destructor of 3,
- Will call the destructor of 4,
- The latter will complete, returning control to the destructor of 3.
- Which will complete, returning control to the destructor of 2.
- Which will complete, returning control to the destructor of 1.
- Which will complete, returning control to the caller.

This is typically of node-based structures: the depth of the call stack is proportional to the depth of the structure. For balanced binary trees, with O(log n) depth, it's typically not an issue; for linked-lists, with O(n) depth, it very much is.

There's no magic here, you *cannot* rely on the destructor of `unique_ptr` to handle the job and must *manually* convert the recursion to iteration every time.

*Note: this typically only manifest for relatively large lists; with stacks a typical 1MB to 8MB, and a call frame taking as little as 16 - 64 bytes, it can take up to 500K elements to trigger the issue. I suggest setting up a test with a few million elements, and testing various operations.*

Comment: How would you convert the recursion of a forwards linked list to iteration? Off the cuff it would seem like you need a backwards pointer to do this effectively.

Comment: @wakey: How insistent are you on destroying the elements _backwards_? If you are fine destroying them _forwards_, you can just go ahead and do it. If you absolutely watns _backwards_, then you can reverse the range to destroy and do it forwards: pop first element, pop 2nd and prepend to 1st, pop 3rd and prepend to 2nd, ... then destroy the new list "forwards".

Comment: @wakey, The key to avoiding the deep recursion is to `release()` each pointer before destructing it and moving along to the next element (the raw pointer `release()` returned).

Comment: @TobySpeight: Rust (where such would be `unsafe`) taught me another method: `auto next = std::move(current->next); current = std::move(next);`. This way memory is still managed automatically: no manual `delete` or tricky stuff :)

Comment: wow thats genius

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM. - that's much better than what I was suggesting.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Could be simplified: [`std::exchange(current, std::move(current->next));`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Indeed, it's the condensed version. I find it easier to explain what happens with the "exploded" version :)

Answer (score 5):

## Move all other classes into `linked_list`

`node_base`, `node` and `linked_list_forward_iterator` are all basically implementation details of `linked_list`. Consider moving them all into `linked_list`. This has several benefits, most notably you don't have to make `node` and `linked_list_forward_iterator` templates anymore, they can just use the template parameter `T` from `linked_list` itself. Furthermore, this avoids polluting the global namespace, and you can rename `linked_list_forward_iterator` to `forward_iterator`.

## Merge `node_base` and `node`

I don't see any benefit of having `node_base` in your code. I would just make a `class node` that looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class linked_list {
    struct node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
        ...
    };

    class forward_iterator {
        ...
        node* m_ptr;
    };
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<node> m_head;
};
```

This simplifies things, for example there is no longer a need for `static_cast`s from `node_base*` to `node*`.

## Increment operators of iterators should return iterators

`operator++()` should always return a reference to either the current or previous `*this`. Otherwise, code expecting the usual behavior of iterators will be broken. It might seem to work in some situations because your increment operators return a `node_ptr`, and `linked_list_forward_iterator` has a constructor that takes a `node_ptr`. Consider making that constructor `explicit` as well.

## Avoid unnecessary initializations

A `std::unique_ptr` has a default constructor that already initializes itself to `nullptr`, so there is no need to do that explicitly yourself.

## No need to repeat template parameters inside a template itself

Inside `class linked_list`, you don't need to write `linked_list<T>`, you can just write `linked_list`.

Comment: Thanks. I like your suggestions. 

I chose to make a separate `node_base` because I needed a node for "before head" which does not have any value associated with it. I thought of using a `std::optional<T> data` in `node<T>` as an alternative to accomodate this "no  data" node but went with the former approach just because that is what `std::forward_list` did.

Comment: You said that a `std::unique_ptr` has a default constructor that already initializes itself to `nullptr`. But is the default constructor called automatically in this case? I know atleast for basic types like int, bool, I need to initialize myself. I always get confused with this.

Comment: Having a generic `node_base` is more useful for a double-linked list...

Comment: For cursor-like things where you want to be able to point "before head", I would typically use a pointer-to-pointer, or in this case a pointer-to-`std::unique_ptr<node>`. You can have it point to either the `linked_list`'s `m_head` or to a `node`'s `next`.

Comment: From practical engineering perspective nested classes have only drawbacks. When the enclosing class is a template, nested classes end up being unique classes, even when they don't depend on template arguments. Nested classes have longer fully qualified symbol names, which results in larger debuginfo but worse readability of names in debugger and in stacktraces. Nested classed cannot be forward declared. An implementation detail namespace is a better solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say un-nested classes are universally the better solution, but I agree with Maxim that the drawbacks of nested classes must be pointed out. See also [SCARY iterators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/what-are-scary-iterators/).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin We can agree to disagree. I don't think longer names in the debugger is an issue we should care about if the source code itself becomes more readable. All the other drawbacks you mention don't apply here; it's a template to begin with so the whole class definition needs to be visible anyway, so forward declarations are not an issue. The `node` class was templated to begin with so they didn't become more unique by moving it into `linked_list`. If you use a detail namespace, you have to ensure names are unique, like `detail::linked_list_node` or `linked_list_detail::node`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Your argument is based on ignoring or downplaying the downsides and that's a rather weak argument.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I indeed am, because I think the downsides are less important here than the nice code organization you get by nesting the classes, which avoids any namespace issues and require less typing, which is what you are downplaying. I would not consider a detail namespace bad either though.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Your definition of _nice code organization_ sounds to be proportional to class definition nesting - the more levels of nesting, the nicer the code. If you maximize such niceness to its extreme you end up with `main` function definiting the top application object class, with all other classes nested in that and so on. Which results in the worst possible code organization and, hence, demonstrates the fallacy of your definition of _nice_ for code organization. Zen of Python is a good source for correct ideas of nice code organization: "Flat is better than nested."

Comment: @G.Sliepen Nested type aliases are great. Nested class definitions - poor engineering practice. The C++ standard library implementations are examples of good engineering (because they have to, tiny faults snowball), they avoid nested class definitions where possible.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem in your design is using `std::unique_ptr`.

The default list destructor invokes `~node_base` (which must be `virtual`, but that would double the size of `node_base` ), which invokes `~unique_ptr` which invokes `~node_base` and so on. With 10MB stack on a 64-bit Linux, destroying a list with 328k+ elements is going to crash with stack overflow.

Comment: That's pretty much what Matthieu M. said.

Comment: Eh?  Can you explain what this answer adds, that wasn't already said?  That comment seems detached from anything here...

Comment: Good catch on the virtual destructor!

Answer (score 2):

You have a good review of the linked list itself.  I'll mostly focus on the tests.

Just a handful of quick observations on the list:

- We don't need to include `<iostream>`.
- It seems that `assert()` is being wrongly used as a run-time test rather than as documentation of an invariant.
- We're missing an implicit conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator`.
- The relational operators comparing two lists can be implemented more simply using standard algorithms (`std::equal()` and `std::lexicographical_compare()` in particular).
- Although we're allowed to specialise `std::swap()`, the standard practice is to define `custom::swap()`, which can be found by ADL.  We probably don't even need this, given that move-assignment (as used by unspecialised `std::swap()`) is cheap.

---

Anyway, let's move on to the tests.  The tests seem almost complete, and exercise the class well.  And they expose no memory errors when run under Valgrind.  That's all good.

Some things could be made even better, though.

We have an empty fixture class.  That doesn't serve any purpose - we can remove that and change our use of `TEST_F()` to `TEST()`.

I'm surprised not to see the simplest test:

```
TEST(LinkedList, DefaultConstructor)
{
    custom::linked_list<int> list;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, list.size());
}
```

Small aside: I've followed the rule in the GoogleTest manual, and avoided using underscore in my test names.

The existing `test_constructors_assignments_and_iterator` contains several independent tests.  I think it's worth separating them into individual tests.  That costs pretty much nothing, and makes life easier for the reader:

```
TEST(LinkedList, DefaultConstructor)
{
    custom::linked_list<int> list;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, list.size());
}

TEST(LinkedList, InitializerListConstructor)
{
    custom::linked_list list{2, 4, 9};
    EXPECT_EQ(3, list.size());
}

TEST(LinkedList, IteratorPairConstructor)
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 5, 6, 2};
    custom::linked_list<int> list(v.begin(), v.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(4, list.size());
}

TEST(LinkedList, CopyAssign)
{
    custom::linked_list list{2, 4, 9};
    EXPECT_EQ(3, list.size());
    custom::linked_list list2{1, 3};
    list = list2;
    EXPECT_EQ(2, list.size());
}

TEST(LinkedList, MoveAssign)
{
    custom::linked_list list{2, 4, 9};
    EXPECT_EQ(3, list.size());
    list = {1, 3};
    EXPECT_EQ(2, list.size());
}

TEST(LinkedList, IteratorForward)
{
    custom::linked_list list{2, 4, 9};
    auto it = list.cbegin();
    EXPECT_EQ(2, *it++);
    EXPECT_EQ(4, *it++);
    EXPECT_EQ(9, *it++);
    EXPECT_EQ(it, list.cend());
}
```

That's longer than what you had, but the reduced density makes comprehension easier.  There's generally only one or two variables in each block now.

Most of the other tests can be split up into simpler, more targeted functions in a similar way.  And we shouldn't need loops in our tests (the loops I see are all element-by-element comparison, but we can just compare entire lists once we have a proven `==` operator).

For example:

```
TEST(LinkedList, EmplaceFront)
{
    custom::linked_list<std::string> list{"one", "two", "three"};
    list.emplace_front("zero");

    const custom::linked_list<std::string> expected{"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
    EXPECT_EQ(list, expected);
}
```

Comment: `assert()` is used to test for programmer error, and AFAICS, all the constraints tested thus are bounds for UB.

Comment: I guess the appropriateness depends on where you draw the line between the "programmer" and the "user".  I take the view that the public functions form the boundary, since they can be called by anyone.  That means we need a reliable means to reject misuse at that point (i.e. a proper test, rather than a debug-only `assert()`), and limit the use of assert just to expressions that depend only on _this class_.  Perhaps you draw the line at a different point, @Deduplicator?

Comment: The public interface is certainly the boundary, but is not a security boundary. Catching that the user broke the contract has a not insignificant cost, which quickly grows unbearably high without completely changing the design and the underlying language. Thus the asserts only catch a small (though the most common) part of it for a cost which should be acceptable when debugging, they don't change the contract nor are remotely enough to verify all preconditions. Whether you want to retain them and pay the cost in released software is your decision.